# Is it possible (and wise) to add more data to the riak search index document, after the original riak object has been saved (with a precommit hook)?

Tags: riak, riak-search

I am using riak (and riak search) to store and index text files. For every file I create a riak object (the text content of the file is the object value) and save it to a riak bucket. That bucket is configured to use the default search analyzer.

I would like to store (and be able to search by) some metadata for these files. Like date of submission, size etc.

So I have asked on IRC, and also given it quite some thought.
Here are some solutions, though they are not as good as I would like:

1. I could have a second "metadata" object that stores the data in question (maybe in another bucket), have it indexed etc. But that is not a very good solution especially if I want to be able to do combined searches like value:someword AND date:somedate
2. I could put the contents of the file inside a JSON object like: {"date":somedate, "value":"some big blob of text"}. This could work, but it's going to put too much load on the search indexer, as it will have to first deserialize a big json object (and those files are sometimes quite big).
3. I could write a custom analyzer/indexer that reads my file object and generates/indexes the metadata in question. The only real problem here is that I have a hard time finding documentation on how to do that. And it is probably going to be a bit of an operational PITA as I will need to push some erlang code to every riak node (and remember to do that when I update the cluster, when I add new nodes etc.) I might be wrong on this, if so, please, correct me.

So the best solution for me would be if I could alter the riak search index document, and add some arbitrary search fields to it, after it gets generated. Is this possible, is this wise, and is there support for this in libraries etc.? I can certainly modify the document in question "manually", as a bucket with index documents gets automatically created, but as I said, I just don't know what's the right thing to do.